# Browserbenchmark "Speedometer" - Chrome is 3x faster than Edge, how?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, benchmarking, microsoft-edge

Recently I came across [Speedometer](http://browserbench.org/Speedometer/). A "browser benchmark that measures the responsiveness of web applications."

In essence, it's running a simple MVC todo-webapp (by the browservendor Webkit owned by Apple Inc.) in a number of popular Javascript frameworks in order to simulate user interaction and then calculates the performance result, which is simply measured in "runs (operations) per minute".

Since I'm currently working on increasing performance for an AngularJS SPA, the different results (depending on hardware and browser) interest me a lot.

Here are my current results:
[Benchmark Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2p77.png)

What we can see, is that regardless of raw hardware power, Chrome seems to run up to three times faster than Edge and also significantly faster than Firefox (all updated to the latest verion).

As stated in the "about" section of Speedometer, "some browser engines use an optimization strategy of doing some work asynchronously to reduce the run time of synchronous operations.". So maybe that's why Chrome (or its js engine V8) is so much faster. I tried to find something on the topic, but didn't come up with anything useful.

More info on the topic can be found here: `ghacks.net/2016/06/23/fastest-browser/`

Comment: What’s your question? Are you looking for a list of every optimization Chrome does that Edge doesn’t?

Comment: this feels like it probably belongs on a different site in the Stack Exchange Network, unless you have *specific code* that you are having issues with?  Right now, it just looks like you are asking about the performance of programs someone else wrote, rather than asking about the performance of the code *you* wrote.

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between how `v8` works and how interpreters used by FF and Edge work. That's the main reason and entire books could be written about those differences.

Comment: @Ryan To be a bit more specific, does Chrome implement some sort of  "optimization strategy of doing some work asynchronously to reduce the run time of synchronous operations" - 
[Webkit](https://webkit.org/blog/3395/speedometer-benchmark-for-web-app-responsiveness/)